# How to check TCP timeout in linux / macos?

Tags: mac-osx, tcp

I have a network problem on my MacOS that i need to troubleshoot. I know that TCP socket has internal timeout that will close connection if remote party is not responding (but no graceful disconnect either). Is it any command/tool i can use to check exact value of this timeout(s)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On macOS you can see all system-set tcp values with

```
$ sysctl net.inet.tcp
```

Interpreted from tcp_var.h, tcp_subr.c, and tcp_timer.c:

- net.inet.tcp.keepidle = keepalive idle timer
- net.inet.tcp.keepintvl = interval to send keepalives
- net.inet.tcp.keepinit = timeout for establishing syn
- net.inet.tcp.mssdflt = Default TCP Maximum Segment Size
- net.inet.tcp.v6mssdflt = Default TCP Maximum Segment Size for IPv6
- net.inet.tcp.minmss = Minmum TCP Maximum Segment Size
- net.inet.tcp.minmssoverload = Number of TCP Segments per Second allowed to be under the MINMSS Size
- net.inet.tcp.rfc1323 = Enable rfc1323 (high performance TCP) extensions
- net.inet.tcp.rfc1644 = Enable rfc1644 (TTCP) extensions
- net.inet.tcp.do_tcpdrain = Enable tcp_drain routine for extra help when low on mbufs
- net.inet.tcp.pcbcount = Number of active PCBs
- net.inet.tcp.icmp_may_rst = Certain ICMP unreachable messages may abort connections in SYN_SENT
- net.inet.tcp.strict_rfc1948 = Determines if RFC1948 is followed exactly
- net.inet.tcp.isn_reseed_interval = Seconds between reseeding of ISN secret
- net.inet.tcp.background_io_enabled = Background IO Enabled
- net.inet.tcp.rtt_min = min rtt value allowed
- net.inet.tcp.randomize_ports = Randomize TCP port numbers
- net.inet.tcp.tcbhashsize = Size of TCP control-block hashtable
- net.inet.tcp.msl = Maximum segment lifetime
- net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive = Assume SO_KEEPALIVE on all TCP connections
- net.inet.tcp.broken_peer_syn_rxmit_thres = Number of retransmitted SYNs before TCP disables rfc1323 and rfc1644 during the rest of attempts
- net.inet.tcp.pmtud_blackhole_detection = Path MTU Discovery Black Hole Detection
- net.inet.tcp.pmtud_blackhole_mss = Path MTU Discovery Black Hole Detection lowered MSS

I believe by default 8 keepalives will be sent before the connection is closed if SO_KEEPALIVE is set.  Times are in milliseconds.

Answer (score 7):

For linux you can use:

```
$ sysctl -a | grep net.ipv4
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can check the keep-alive value with:

```
$ netstat -o
```

Comment: netstat doesn't accept the '-o' option for me in Mac OS X 10.6.6

Answer (score 1):

Maybe unrelated, but works for me:

I'm trying to determine the ssh/tcp interactive timeout to one of our servers, so i just:

```
date; ssh host.domain 'sleep 10000'; date
```

example output:

```
Thu May 24 12:22:39 CEST 2018
packet_write_wait: Connection to 172.29.1.27 port 22: Broken pipe
Thu May 24 14:22:40 CEST 2018
```

Comment: You could do that using `time`, like: `time ssh hostname 'sleep 10000'`

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the initial timeout for establishing a TCP connection is not configured as a value in seconds. Instead, there's a [hardcoded](http://arthurchiao.art/blog/customize-tcp-initial-rto-with-bpf/) initial RTO *(Retransmission TimeOut)* of 1 second and a configurable number of retries (with exponential back-off). To quote the [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt):

> **tcp_syn_retries** - INTEGER
> Number of times initial SYNs for an active TCP connection attempt
> will be retransmitted. Should not be higher than 127. **Default value
> is 6**, which corresponds to 63seconds till the last retransmission
> with the current initial RTO of 1second. **With this the final timeout**
> for an active TCP connection attempt **will happen after 127 seconds.**

[Reportedly](https://www.justsomestuff.co.uk/wiki/doku.php/linux/syn_tcp_timeout), the specific default value can vary depending on the distribution. You can `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries` to see the currently configured value.

If you're using `systemd-sysctl.service`, [you can override this by creating a file in /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf](https://serverfault.com/a/954509/58957), e.g.:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "sys.net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 4" >> /etc/sysctl.d/local.conf'
sudo reboot
```