# What happens to tcp packets when they are unable to finish the 3 way handshake?

Tags: iptables, tcp, flags

Firewall for a virtual dedicated server.
I was looking into how to prevent a FIN scan and it got me thinking about the consequences.
A lot of people are using this rule:

-p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN -j DROP

So when someone sends me a packet with a FIN = 1 , I'm unable to send FIN/ACK back.
It seems unlikely but does that mean my established connection won't be stopped ?
How does that work ? Does my connection stay alive and if so, for how long ?

How does that actually work when someone closes his / her browser ? It sends a FIN to my server, my server replies with FIN/ACK ... but the browser is unable to receive that, right ? Who gets the packet, where does it go ?

And what if ... a remote machine sends my server a SYN, my reply is SYN/ACK and let's say that I'm not getting the ACK back, how long is my server waiting for it ?

Is there a name for unfinished 3 way handshakes ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a name for unfinished 3 way handshakes

This is called a [half-open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_half-open) connection.

> So when someone sends me a packet with a FIN = 1 , I'm unable to send FIN/ACK back.
>   It seems unlikely but does that mean my established connection won't be stopped? How does that work ? Does my connection stay alive and if so, for how long?

It will eventually timeout. See also the TIME_WAIT state.

- [Which is the default TCP connect timeout in Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/193160/which-is-the-default-tcp-connect-timeout-in-windows)
- [How to check TCP timeout in linux / macos?](https://serverfault.com/questions/216956/how-to-check-tcp-timeout-in-linux-macos)
- [Setting TIME_WAIT TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337115/setting-time-wait-tcp)

Comment: Having had the exact problem described, you diagnose this problem by seeing w-a-y more TCP_WAIT listings in `netstat` then there should be.

Comment: component in a denial of service, anyone? :-)